# make css menu display vertical rather than horizontal

Tags: html, css

Here is my css code:

```
.tab-box {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
a.tabLink {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.tab-box a {
  border:1px solid #666666;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color: #eee;
  background:#666666;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  display:block;
}
.tab-box a.activeLink { 
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color:#666666;
  border-bottom: 0; 
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.tabcontent {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 99%;
}
.hide { display: none;}
.small { color: #999; margin-top: 100px; border: 1px solid #EEE; padding: 5px; font-size: 9px; font-family:Calibri; }
```

and my HMTL:

```
<div style="display:inline; float:left; width:18%; border:1px solid black;" class="tab-box">
    <a href="#companyinfo" class="tabLink activeLink">Company</a> 
    <a href="#contacts" class="tabLink">Contacts</a>
</div>
```

how can i change this to display down the page, vertically, rather than horizontal?

I have tried adding `display:block;` to `.tab-box a` but that didnt make any difference

Comment: but it shows vertically already?

Comment: remove the `float:left` and make `display:block`  in this code: `<div style="display:inline; float:left; width:18%; border:1px solid black;" class="tab-box">`  and then look.

Comment: still its vertical [here is the code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGofb)

Answer (score 0):

Give to your links display:inline-block or float:left (if you don't want a small gap between links)

```
tab-box a {

 display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mhCkc)

```
<div style="display:inline; float:left; width:18%; border:1px solid black;" class="tab-box">
    <a href="#companyinfo" class="tabLink activeLink">Company</a> 
    <a href="#contacts" class="tabLink">Contacts</a>
</div>

.tab-box {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
    padding-bottom:5px;
  text-align:center;
}
a.tabLink {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.tab-box a {
  border:1px solid #666666;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color: #eee;
  background:#666666;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  display:block;
}
.tab-box a.activeLink { 
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color:#666666;
  border-bottom: 0; 
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.tabcontent {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 99%;
}
.hide { display: none;}
.small { color: #999; margin-top: 100px; border: 1px solid #EEE; padding: 5px; font-size: 9px; font-family:Calibri; }
.tab-box a {
  display:inline-block;
```

}